# Return new ID added by INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADD_CUSTOMER]
(
    @CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
    (    
       CUSTOMER_NAME
    )
    VALUES
    (
       @CUSTOMER_NAME 
    )
END
```

How can I get a unique ID after I add data to my database? Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is the ID an identity column?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s +1 and [this is actually a rule in VS code analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: You need to better define what you mean by "Unique ID" - is this an identity column, a uniqueidentifier with NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID() as the default, something else entirely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ID` column is of type `INT IDENTITY`, then you can just use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADD_CUSTOMER]
   (@CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(100))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_NAME)
    VALUES(@CUSTOMER_NAME)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()  -- this will retrieve and send back the newly inserted IDENTITY value
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have shown you how to get the ID if it's an IDENTIY. I read "Unique ID" and assumed your ID is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER. So first, I created a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER](
    [CUSTOMER_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CUSTOMER_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CUSTOMER_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then I created a Stored Procedure that looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADD_CUSTOMER]
(
    @CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CUSTOMER_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
    (
        CUSTOMER_ID,
        CUSTOMER_NAME
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @CUSTOMER_ID,
        @CUSTOMER_NAME 
    )

    SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID
END
```

And finally I executed the Stored Procedure and got the new CUSTOMER_ID back:

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @CUSTOMER_NAME varchar(100) = N'Joe'

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[SP_ADD_CUSTOMER] 
   @CUSTOMER_NAME
GO
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID has syntax error , can you check your example again please ?

Comment: user2869820 the syntax is correct, there's no error.  Are you sure you are running the entire code block (not just the "SELECT @CUSTOMER_ID AS CUSTOMER_ID"?

Comment: I edited the answer to provide code for everything you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

This is assuming your "Unique ID" is an `IDENTITY` column. If that is not the case, please clarify your question.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ADD_CUSTOMER]
  @CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(100),
  @NewID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.CUSTOMER(CUSTOMER_NAME) SELECT @CUSTOMER_NAME;
    SET @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

As an aside, [always use the schema prefix on object names](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). Also, [please don't use the sp_ prefix on procedure names](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).